# How to run async task inside one fragment (when the fragment is still invisible) and retain the values

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have two async task running in a fragment, let's call F1.

The fragment takes 4/5 seconds to load data when it is visible (I have put a progress bar there)

what I want to achieve is:

to run those async task in the fragment as soon as I open the application (loads a different fragment) so that I don't have to show the progress bar when I open that particular fragment (F1), and retain the data until (i) refresh button is clicked or (ii) application is closed/restarted.

I have tried to put the execute() of the async task inside a method and try to call the method from my main fragment. But I am getting error there, because my post execute method has some view attached to it.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), mNoOfColumns));
        adapterDod=new AdapterDotd(getActivity(),data);
        adapterDod.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if(AsyncTaskCount == AsyncTaskRequested) {
            lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        recyclerView.invalidate();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterDod);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i advice you to work with `fragment` inside `viewpager` that allows you to do load your `fragment` data without being visible

Comment: I am using it. Thanks for the advise.